# Problem in my program of bisection method

Tags: python, methods

I am getting an error when running the following code:

```py
def f(x):
    return x**3-x-2

def bisection(f,a,b,app=0.3):
    Fa,Fb=f(a),f(b)
    if Fa*Fb>0:
        raise Exception('Fails')
    for i in range(a,b):
        x=(a+b)/2
        if f*Fa>0:
            a=x
        else:
            b=x
    return x

print(bisection(f,{'a':1,'b':2},0.00003))
```

Below the output I get when running the script above:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'dict' and 'int'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. In the bisection function you are supposed to give 4 arguments, *f* which is a function, *a* and *b* which are numbers, and a fourth argument *app* which is not used in your function currently.

The first issue is that you are giving a dictionary instead of the *a* and *b* arguments. The following will work better.

```
bisection(f=f,a=1,b=2,app=0.00003)
```

I do not know the bisection method, but from what I can tell from a quick scan on the bisection method from Wikipedia, it should be an **N_MAX** variable which tells how many iterations you will allow before breaking.

Therefore you should not use a **for loop** and use a **while loop** instead.

The new algorithm is then

```
def f(x):
    return x**3-x-2

def bisection(f,a,b,app=0.3, N_MAX=10):
    Fa,Fb=f(a),f(b)
    if Fa*Fb>0:
        raise Exception('Fails')
    
    n = 0
    while n < N_MAX:
        x=(a+b)/2
        if f(x)==0 or ((a-b)/2) < app:
            return x
        n += 1
        if f(x) > 0:
            a = x
        else:
            b = x
    return x

print(bisection(f,1,2,0.00003, 10))
>>> 1.5
```